# Grub boot loader failed to install when installing Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, 18.04

While installing Ubuntu I got the following error:

> The `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package failed to install into / Target /. Without the grub boot loader, the installation system will not boot.

What I should do now? Please tell me.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you add a link to a screenshot, or write the exact error message.